# CosmosDB accent (diacritics) insensitive query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I query CosmosDB ignoring accents?
Example:

```json
{"id": "1", "name": "Émpresa 1" }
{"id": "2", "name": "empresa 2" }
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM container_name
WHERE name LIKE 'empresa%'
```

I want to retrieve both records from this query, how can I do that?
If it's not possible "out of the box" then is there any workaround?

Comment: Can’t you do something like “ SELECT * FROM container_name WHERE name LIKE '%mpresa%'”?

Comment: this may work assuming you know where the accent is

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is just **`'%mpresa%'`** as the first item has starting letter with `'E'` while second one has `'e'`

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name LIKE "%mpresa%"
```

Demo

```
 [
    {
        "ItemId": "1",
        "name": "Émpresa 1",
        "id": "c599d43a-a88b-441f-b6df-361380f05eac",
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "2",
        "name": "empresa 2",
        "id": "ed894a28-f439-4a23-88e2-80d29ff106e0",
    }
]
```

If you want to perform free text search you may consider the feature supported for SQL API with Azure cognitive search [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb)

Comment: this will work for this particular test case, but if he needs a different query or the accent is in another place it won't work

Comment: you mean like free text search?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Please be sure to only include formatted text, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Also, no need to include Cosmos DB's internal properties.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sure, I have been always pasting the image interms of samples. will keep in mind

Comment: @Sajeetharan - when you have to illustrate something with a screenshot, then go for it. But in the case of code, queries, data, etc, this is where it's important to use formatted text, especially for those who use screen readers (and that's just one of many reasons enumerated in that meta post).

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB will save data in the specified encoding of your text. As 'É' and 'e' are not the same, I believe you have two options:

1- Replace special chars to it's root form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086575/1384539

2- Use a Search Engine (e.g. Azure Cognitive Search) which will to the previous work for you